# Generate correlated AR process for given correlation between demand series

Tags: time-series, arima, random-generation

How can I generate two correlated $AR(1)$ data series with given correlation between $d_{1,t}$ and $d_{2,t}$, $r_{12}$, where $\rho_{12}$ is correlation between the two error series
$$d_{1,t}=\mu+\phi_1d_{1,(t−1)}+e_{1}(t)\quad\quad d_{2,t}=\mu+\phi_2d_{2,(t-1)}+e_{2}(t)$$

$e_1$ and $e_2$ are not the same and $r_{12}$ is desired correlation between $d_{1,t}$ and $d_{2,t}$?

The relations between $r_{12}$ and $\rho_{12}$ is:

$$r_{12}=\rho_{12}*\sqrt{(1-\phi_1^2)*(1-\phi_2^2)}/ (1-\phi_1\phi_2)$$

one example for: $\phi_1=.3$, $\phi_2=-.8$ AND $r_{12}=-.8$;
the problem is, for this example $\rho_{12}$ is $-1.7,$ now how can I generate the error terms where the correlation between the two error series $\rho_{12}$ is not between $-1$ and $+1$?

Comment: You need to generate random numbers from $e_{1}$ and $e_{2}$ jointly, such as by a multivariate normal distribution (using the covariance between the error terms). Then using those values and the other known variables you can simply plug them in to $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the PROBLEM is: I'd like to generate two correlated series with r12=-.8 or -.9 but for these values ρ12=-1.7 while ρ12 must be -1<ρ12<+1

Comment: to generate e1 and e2 jointly I need ρ12, how can i calculate ρ12 ?

Comment: It is simply telling you that it is not possible to have that high a correlation between the two series.  Because they have such different AR coefficients, even if you fed in identical error sequences they would wander away from each other all over the place.